# angularjs file upload with dynamic variable name node.js backend

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express

I am uploading an array of images from angularjs application to express js backend, in angular i am building the `formData` like this

```
$scope.botSays.forEach(function(item, index) {
  if (item.activeType == '1') {
    formData.append('imageFiles' + index, item.imageFile);
  }
});
```

In express.js

in the server side

```
req.botSays.forEach(function(item, index){
  //print the image
  console.log(req.files.imageFiles + index);
})
```

But I am getting `NaN`

Comment: What is `req.botSays`?

Comment: its actually an array and i am getting the index properly

Comment: Where is it coming from? Some sort of middleware? Custom? What if you `.log(item)` instead?

Comment: Its coming from `post` request there is no middleware

Comment: AFAIK it's `req.body.*` and [body-parser](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req.body), also to upload multiple files you need middleware that supports this, like [multer](https://github.com/expressjs/multer)

Comment: Maybe try `req.files['imageFiles'+index]` ? Showing us what each `item` and `req.files` looks like will help answer this better. What middleware are you using to handle the file upload?

Comment: I am using express file upload